# Raster misalignment when gridded

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal

I have a shapefile (green point layer below) in which I use `gdal_grid` to grid it into raster and then `gdalwarp` to transform from the source reference system (EPSG:27700) to the destination reference system (EPSG:3857).

However, as you can see the below, once gridded it moves position and becomes misaligned.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a small point dataset as test data?

Comment: @user30184 yeah, how shall I share it?

Comment: Through a download link.

Comment: Unfortunately .shp part is not enough for a complete shapefile. Add also .shx, .dbf, and .prj parts. Or save the vector data as GeoPackage of GeoJSON. Then one file contains everything.

Comment: QGIS (or Proj in the background) seems to offer 9 alternative transformations between EPSG:27700 and EPSG:3857. It may be that for some reason different transformations get selected for a) transforming the point data and b) for transforming the gridded raster. I would convert the point data into EPSG:3857 first and run gdal_grid agains points which are already in EPSG:3857. I recommend to document what transformation was applied in the conversion. I hope you can copy the Proj pipeline from the QGIS user interface or then you can list the candidates with `projinfo -s epsg:27700 -t epsg:3857`.